# Django select box size option

Tags: django, html-select

I have three drop down select boxes, which I have to expand for web visibility reasons, with the size='' option.  If I select an option from each box I receive no errors, but if I leave one or more boxes without a selection, I receive an error:

```
<select id="pathology_id" name="pathology_id" size="5">
    {% for pathology in pathology_list %}
    <option value="{{ pathology.id }}">{{ pathology.pathology }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="commodity_id" name="commodity_id" size="5">
    {% for commodity in commodity_list %}
    <option value="{{ commodity.id }}">{{ commodity.commodity }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="technology_id" name="technology_id" size="5">
    {% for technology in technology_list %}
    <option value="{{ technology.id }}">{{ technology.technology }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

ERROR:
MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"Key 'pathology_id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'q': [u''],
```

How to code the view to accept a drop down box having no selection?

Answer (score 1):

you can surround the for loops with an if statement if any of your lists are empty.

For example,

```
{% if technology_list %}
    {% for technology in technology_list %} {{ technology.technology }} {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Lastly, in the view, you can check to see the posted item is in the request dictionary.

```
if 'technology' in request.POST:
    tech = request.POST['technology']
```

-----**Update**-----

First off, you should probably be using [django forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) to do this. Secondly, you should be using stackoverflow to ask specific questions. You shouldn't be using it as a method to fix your code.

Lastly, the error seems to be thrown for the following line:

```
pathology_id = request.GET['pathology_id']
```

The problem is that the key 'pathology_id' isn't inside the GET dictionary. If you have a default value for this field, you can do something like this:

```
pathology_id = 'default_value'
if 'pathology_id' in request.GET:
    pathology_id = request.GET['pathology_id']
```

Otherwise, if you don't have a default value, you obviously can't get an Pathology object without an ID. You will then have to handle the case when nothing is selected.

```
if 'pathology_id' in request.GET:
    pathology_id = request.GET['pathology_id']

    #rest of your code

else:
    #code when no pathology_id is selected
```